# Multiple shlib providers for libiomp5.so

Tags: yocto, lib, openembedded

I did bitbake for a customized recipe which used to install Intel MKL.

The link to download MKL:
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/mpi-library/choose-download.html

After did

```
bitbake foo
```

it shows:

```
ERROR: lmkl-1.0-r0 do_package: lmkl: Multiple shlib providers for libiomp5.so: lmkl, lmkl (used by files: /home/rsa/foo/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/lmkl/1.0-r0/packages-split/lmkl/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166/linux/mkl/benchmarks/hpcg/bin/xhpcg_skx)
ERROR: lmkl-1.0-r0 do_package: lmkl: Multiple shlib providers for libtbbmalloc.so.2: lmkl, lmkl (used by files: /home/rsa/foo/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/lmkl/1.0-r0/packages-split/lmkl/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166/linux/tbb/lib/intel64_lin/gcc4.8/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2)
ERROR: lmkl-1.0-r0 do_package: lmkl: Multiple shlib providers for libiomp5.so: lmkl, lmkl (used by files: /home/rsa/foo/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/lmkl/1.0-r0/packages-split/lmkl/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166/linux/mkl/benchmarks/hpcg/bin/xhpcg_avx)
ERROR: lmkl-1.0-r0 do_package: lmkl: Multiple shlib providers for libiomp5.so: lmkl, lmkl (used by files: /home/rsa/foo/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/lmkl/1.0-r0/packages-split/lmkl/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166/linux/mkl/benchmarks/hpcg/bin/xhpcg_knl)
ERROR: lmkl-1.0-r0 do_package: lmkl: Multiple shlib providers for libiomp5.so: lmkl, lmkl (used by files: /home/rsa/foo/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/lmkl/1.0-r0/packages-split/lmkl/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166/linux/mkl/benchmarks/hpcg/bin/xhpcg_avx2)
ERROR: lmkl-1.0-r0 do_package: lmkl: Multiple shlib providers for libtbbmalloc.so.2: lmkl, lmkl (used by files: /home/rsa/foo/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/lmkl/1.0-r0/packages-split/lmkl/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166/linux/tbb/lib/ia32_lin/gcc4.8/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2)
```

Here is my part of bb:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "bash coreutils"
DEPENDS += " coreutils-native"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-so file-rdeps already-stripped ldflags arch libdir installed-vs-shipped"
```

Any config I should set to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

This should work.

```
do_package_qa[noexec] = "1"
EXCLUDE_FROM_SHLIBS = "1"
```